# Typescript: type arrays with different type for each element

Tags: arrays, typescript, casting, jestjs

I'd like to define a typed array, specifying a type for the first element, another type for the second and so on...

In fact, I'm trying to get rid of the following casts:

```
const cases = [
  [ 'http://gmail.com', false ],
  [ '/some_page', true ],
  [ 'some_page', false ]
]

describe("'isInternalLink' utility", () => {
  test.each(cases)(
    "given %p as argument, returns %p", (link, result) => {
      expect(
        isInternalLink(<string>link)
      ).toEqual(
        <boolean> result
      )
    }
  )
})
```

As you can see, each element in `cases` is an array which has a string as first element and a boolean as second...

Just to be clear, I don't want an array of `string | boolean` type, I want an array whose first element is a string and whose second element is a boolean.

Any idea how to improve this???

Comment: Use `casses = [..... ] as const`

Comment: Interesting, `as const` doesn't work right in this case (at least in my vscode).  I wonder if the typing for `test.each` needs some work? @TitianCernicova-Dragomir

Comment: I get this error: Type 'readonly ["http://gmail.com", false]' is not assignable to type 'string'. What a shame, that would have been the perfect solution to this problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cases` is an [Array](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array), and each element in `cases` is a [Tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple), so if you define `cases` like this:

```
const cases: [string, boolean][] = ...
```

...or alternatively like this:

```
const cases: Array<[string, boolean]> = ....
```

...then `link` will be a `string` and `result` will be a `boolean` and your test can be simplified to this:

```
describe("'isInternalLink' utility", () => {
  test.each(cases)(
    "given %p as argument, returns %p", (link, result) => {
      expect(isInternalLink(link)).toEqual(result)
    }
  )
})
```

Comment: YES, exactly what I was looking for (too bad the `as const` option wouldn't work in this scenario...)

Comment: can I use this while inside another interface?